# Events on elements created by jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I'm still learning jquery and I'm facing an issue that probably a lot of people have been facing which is just logic but I can't seem to find a good way to learn how to do that.

**So my issue is the following:**
I'm creating elements called `.lieu` on the page using jquery. Basically, when you enter a text and click "OK" you created another `.lieu` that is supposed to display the text *"en passant par le bois des lutins"* in the `destinations` tab.
The first one that is created with html is working but not the other ones.
It seems the script is able to execute on the elements created using html (that's probably due to:)

```
$( document ).ready(function() {});
```

How can I make that work using the good method?
Thanks a lot.

```js
    $(".validate").click( function(){
    var name = $(this).closest(".envies").find("input[name='name']").val();
    var lieu = $("<div />", {
        "class": "lieu"
    })
    .css({
        left: 0,
        top: 0
    })
    .append($("<p>"+name+"</p>"))
    .appendTo(document.body);});

    $(".lieu").on("mouseenter", function(checklieu) { 
     var ordredestinations = $("<div />", {
        "class": "lieuliste"
    })
     .css({

     })
     .append($("<p>en passant par le bois des lutins</p>"))
     .appendTo(".destinations");
    });
```

```css
.destinations {
  background-color: lightgrey; 
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.envies {
  background-color: grey; 
  position: fixed;
  right: 300px;
  top: 0;
    width: 250px;
  height: 50px;

}


.lieu{
  position: absolute;
  left:0px;
  top: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 100px;       /* The same as your div height */
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

    <div class="lieu"><p>bois des lutins</p></div>
    <div class="destinations"></div>
    <div class="envies">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" size="10" placeholder="name">
        <button class="validate">OK</button>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: It looks like you can simplify this quite a bit. Look up jquery append. Append means 'add to the end', so you don't have to go through finding a specific item and going to the last item etc etc. You just have to append, and it goes at the end.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help, I'll check that tomorrow.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "not working".  What exactly is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A think I see your problem.

When a document (webpage) loads, specific targeted jQuery functions like yours..

```
$(".validate").click( function() {

   // ...

});

// and...

$(".lieu").on("mouseenter", function() {

   // ...

});
```

..will only bind upon the document being ready, more than like because you are using these inside `$(document).ready(function()`. So when doc is ready, the above 2 functions run and bind.

Running functions like you are within doc ready is good practice.

However, if you intend to automatically bind existing executed functions to newly added document elements.. then your first 2 functions are out of scope.

You need to look into `.on()` https://api.jquery.com/on/

For example, if you want newly added document elements like `.lieu` divs, to be hit by your `mouseover` function, then you use `.on` function like this...

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".lieu", function()
```

The `.on()` second param is the `.lieu` selector, within `$(document)` as the main jQuery selector object.

Meaning if you append any number of new `.lieu` divs to the `document` html, using `.on()` selector param within `$(document)` will always be in scope of the mouseover event on this selector.

Comment: yep! you are right, I found the an article about `.on()` but I thought I was doing this right.
Will definitely learn that!
Thanks a lot